# Voltmeter Question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electric-circuits

I understand that a voltmeter is used for measuring potential electrical difference, but how exactly should said voltmeter be connected with the resistor in circuit?

Comment: Ideal voltmeters have infinite resistance so no current can flow through them.  This constrains your options.  Hint: you can't connect the voltmeter in series with the resister because that'd create an open circuit.

Comment: Are you referring to placing them parallel to other resistors?

Comment: Decide what voltage drop you want to measure and place the voltmeter in parallel with that element. So if you put the voltmeter in parallel with a resistor you will measure the voltage drop across that resistor.

Comment: Don't go near the circuit (or anything else electric) until you have a much better grasp of the concepts.  I'm serious -if you have to ask this question, you are putting your safety at risk.

Comment: Would http://electronics.stackexchange.com/ be a better home for this question?

Comment: I'm just trying to learn conceptual stuff.

Answer (score 1):

- Parallel connected circuit elements have *identical* voltages.
- Series connected circuit elements have *identical* currents.

Now, fill in the blanks:

To measure the voltage *across* a circuit element, the voltmeter should be placed in ***_*_** with the circuit element.

To measure the current *through* a circuit element, the ammeter should be placed in ***_*_** with the circuit element.